# How to get array elements using a list of index in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Consider the following document in mongoDB:

```
{words:['a','b','c','d','e','f']}
```

I know it's easy to get a single element or a range in mongodb using `$arrayElemAt` or `$slice`.

But how can I get multiple elements by giving a list of indices?

For example, if I have a list of indices:

`[0,2,5]`

the expected result is:

```
{words:['a','c','f']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your array as `in` parameter into [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and then use [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) operator:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            words: {
                $map: {
                    input: [0,2,5],
                    as: "index",
                    in: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$words", "$$index" ] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2Kbn47dK1OD)